Why does "is Type" allocate memory, but not "is Type variable"?
I have the following code, where I was trying to get the memory allocated when using the "is" operator, by using GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes before and after the operation. When doing thing is MyStruct I get that 24 bytes are allocated, but when doing thing is MyStruct meow I get 0 bytes.
This looks like quite a weird behaviour to me, I'd expect both to either allocate or not. Is this something expected, and why would that be the case? Or is there something I'm missing regarding GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes?
using System;
using static System.Console;

interface IInterface {}
struct MyStruct : IInterface {}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyStruct a;
        Meow(a);
        ReadLine();
    }

    static void Meow<T>(T thing) where T : IInterface
    {
        long beforeBytes = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);

        bool isMyStruct = thing is MyStruct;  // Allocates 24 bytes
        // bool isMyStruct = thing is MyStruct meow;  // No allocation?

        long afterBytes = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);

        WriteLine($"Before: {beforeBytes}");
        WriteLine($"After:  {afterBytes}");
        WriteLine($"Diff:   {afterBytes - beforeBytes}");

        WriteLine();
        WriteLine(isMyStruct);
    }
}

Output of thing is MyStruct:
Before: 765712
After:  765736
Diff:   24

True

Output of thing is MyStruct meow:
Before: 765712
After:  765712
Diff:   0

True


I cannot reproduce. Both versions show a “Diff” of 0. What version of .NET are you using?

You have to step into the shoes of the C# compiler, ildasm.exe can provide insight.  And the Debug > Windows > Disassembly tool window.  Note the box instructions you see in ildasm, 1 for the existing snippet, 2 for the pattern matching version.  So no surprise that you'll see 24 bytes, the minimum size of an object in 64-bit mode.  The jitter gets quite smart about the pattern matching flavor, it knows how to eliminate boxing completely by inlining the code.  Good job.

@HansPassant I also saw that on SharpLab (where I couldn't reproduce) too, and was a bit confused. The jitter can eliminate two boxings, but not one boxing on its own (?)

There's a related issue on github: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/58554

@Sweeper It's .NET 8.0

@HansPassant I did check the IL, but it's the first time I've done that and I'm not knowledgeable about it. Like for Sweeper, the 2 boxings confused me, I assumed if the IL has boxing instructions the allocation would happen, but the jitter can actually avoid them? And if so, I assume it not being able to do it for the non-pattern matching version would just be an oversight by the jitter developers? Otherwise it doesn't make sense to me.

Digging a bit more, indeed "by default" the check would do the boxing, and the JIT (or AOT) compiler can just optimize it out. There's nothing special with either "is type" or "is type variable", and both versions can allocate or not allocate with very slight changes to the other code, I assume because the small changes make the JIT compiler behave a bit differently (I've checked with the AOT compiler, and it removes the boxings that the jitter can't, I assume because it has no time restriction). @HansPassant do you want to add your own answer, or shall I just add one mentioning your comment?

In the second case, memory is also allocated due to boxing, but since the object is obtained back, anboxing occurs
IL code with T is TestStruct
IL code with T is TestStruct strct

When you use is Type, you're simply checking if an object is of a certain type. This involves creating a temporary object of the specified type to perform the check. So, in this case, memory is allocated for this temporary object, hence you see memory allocation when using GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes.
However, when you use is Type variable, you're not creating a temporary object. Instead, you're checking if the specified variable is of the specified type. Since you're not creating any new objects in this case, there is no additional memory allocation, and hence you see 0 bytes allocated.

"This involves creating a temporary object of the specified type to perform the check" That cannot be the case, there's no object created, only boxing of an existing object.

@Trisibo to be fair: there is no such thing as "boxing an existing object" - objects (by which I mean anything that has na object header, i.e. allocated on the heap) are never boxed; values can be boxed, which involves allocating an object (the box); boxing is absolutely an allocating operation

@MarcGravell Well, yes, I used "object" loosely. I know boxing allocates, but of course not an object of the type being checked, which is the main mistake of the answer

@MarcGravell I'm wrong and dumb, aren't I? Boxing indeed creates an object of the type being checked (at least kind of, I guess it depends on how you interpret it). The actual main issue of the answer is that boxing has to happen with both "is type" and "is type variable", the check can't be done on the variable itself, as far as I know it needs an object (in the C# sense), just like "GetType" needs an object

Plus, of course, if the check was done on the variable it would always be true anyway...
